# fail to make .so from .cpp

Tags: java, android, c++

I was learning JNI and I met a problem that both my friend and me cannot solve it.
I try

```
Jni_Sum.cpp -fpic -shared -o Jni_Sum.so
```

and some other ways. then it shows

```
Jni_Sum.cpp:7:17: fatal error: jni.h: #include <jni.h>
```

I have `jawt_md.h  jni.h  jni_md.h  Jni_Sum.cpp  Sumtest.h  Sumtest.h~  Sumtest.java` in my folder.
Is there any people can help me? thanks

Comment: I would like to upload my files if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Those switches make me think you are using gcc.

Try adding a -I switch to your compile command line.

In example, if you have jdk installed at /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/ then try adding :

-I /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/linux

Adapt to your system and particular installation.

Comment: I use ubuntu system, there is no linux folder in my jdk64 folder.

Comment: cd jdk64folder; find . -iname jni.h; That will locate the folder which contains the jni.h file. That is the folder you need for your include switch.

Comment: I cannot use "-I", it is not found

Comment: That is the problem. Compilation fails because it cannot find jni.h . Try "locate jni.h" in the commandline